# Storing ceil( divison ) in an integer in c++

Tags: c++, ceil

Sorry for the maybe stupid question. I wanted to write a straightforward c++ code that takes the number of people and returns how many baking trays of 12 muffins I have to bake when everyone gets two muffins.

So I read in the number so people via cin in the variable "personen" and after that, I calculate the number of the baking trays (variable "bleche") via

```
  int bleche = ceil(personen/6);
```

But my code doesn't seem to round up the number. For example if personen = 290, trays is 48 (and not 49).

Can someone tell me why?

Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  int personen;
  cout <<"Personen?";
  cin >> personen;

  int bleche = ceil(personen/6);

  cout << "Sie muessen " << bleche << " Backbleche backen." << endl;
  cout << bleche*12 - personen*2 << " Muffins bleiben zur freien Verwendung uebrig." << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are performing integer division. Try `personen/6.0f` instead

Comment: Oh my god! Thank u so much! That worked

Comment: Alternately, provided that `personen >= 0` : `int bleche = (personen+5) / 6`. This is much faster, for cases when this matters (for example, computation on pixels).

Comment: @prapin solution is correct. Using floats is not.